# I am not able to connect SQL server database?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have SQL server 2008R2 (instance name - SQLServer2008) and SQL server 2012(Instance Name - MSSQLSERVER2012) was installed in my local PC.

I can able to login using SQL 2012.

E.g:

```
server Name : .\MSSQLSERVER2012
Authentication : SQL server Authentication
User name : sa
password  : test123
```

But same way i tried to login SQL server 2008R2. (I tried to login using Windows Authentication and SQL Server Authentication, But i am not able to login. I am getting bellow error.)

E.g:

```
server Name : .\SQLServer2008
Authentication : SQL server Authentication
User name : sa
password  : test123
```

ERROR:

```
A network-related or instance-specific errror occured while establishing a connection to sql server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance namme is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections, (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 connection string is not valid) (Microsoft SQL server, Error: 87)
```

Comment: Error states `connection string is not valid`, so where is your connection string?

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand your question. Because I tried to login using SQL server Management studio only.